# converts decimal number to its binary form in nibbles

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

Here's my code, the program should ask for a number between 0-65,535 and it should output its decimal form in nibbles

```
.model small
.data
prompt db "Input an integer in the interval [0, 65535]: $", 0
number dw 0h
digitCounter db 0h
place_value dw 0h
number_of_bits dw 0h
two db 2

.stack 4096
.code
readInt proc
mov ah, 01h ; reads a character from the keybaord and loads it into the AL register
int 21h
ret 
readInt endp
; after readInt, AL has the integer itself, and AX has 0001 XXXX

newline proc
mov dl, 10
mov ah, 02h
int 21h
mov dl, 13
mov ah, 02h
int 21h
ret
newline endp

main proc

; Clearing data
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax

; Start of main() proper
call newline
mov dx, offset prompt
mov ah, 09h
int 21h


DLOOP:
cmp digitCounter, 05h ; if we have already read 6 digits
je PROG_CONT ; we jump
call readInt ; puts the read character into the AH register     

cmp al, 0Dh 
je PROG_CONT

sub al, 30h ; after this point, the read character is sure to be an integer
; subtract 30h to it to get the actual value
mov ah, 0h ; makes the higher bits of ah 0
push ax ; pushes that integer into the stack
inc digitCounter
jmp DLOOP
PASSED_ONES:
dec digitCounter
add number, cx; ; adds the special case (the ones digit), to the number
cmp digitCounter, 0h
je ones_cont
inc place_value ; move to the next place value of the number (tens)
PROG_CONT:
pop cx ; pops the topmost element of the stack to register CX
cmp place_value, 0h ; at the beginning of the iteration this is known to be the ones digit
je PASSED_ONES
mov ax, 10 ; first we take the place value multiplier, e.g., tens - 10, hundreds - 100
mul place_value ; the result is stored in the DX:AX augmented register
mov bx, ax ; move the result to another register because we will use AX again for another multiplication
mov ax, cx ; now we move the popped value from the CX register to the AX register
mul bx ; AX = contains the digit, BX = contains the place value, DX:AX - result
add number, ax ; add the result to the number

mov ax, 0Ah ; first we take the place value multiplier, e.g., tens - 10, hundreds - 100
mul place_value
mov place_value, ax

dec digitCounter
jnz PROG_CONT

; after this point, the variable number contains the number itself 
ones_cont:  
mov ax, number

do:
div two ; after division, the remainder (the digit we want) is stored in the AH register
mov cl, ah ; we copy ah to bh so that we can use AX again
push cx ; the stack now has the digits of the number in reverse order, so when we pop it
; the first value we pop is the value of the largest place value
inc number_of_bits
mov ah, 0h ; clear out AH because AX will be used again for division
cmp al, 01h ; we continue dividing the quotient, which is stored in AL and if it's zero, we move on
jne do

continue:
inc number_of_bits
mov cx, 01h
push cx

mov ax, number_of_bits
jmp EVENING_OUT_DEM_BITS
APPEND_ZERO:
mov bl, 0h
push bx ; pushes the value '0' into the stack
inc number_of_bits
mov ax, number_of_bits
EVENING_OUT_DEM_BITS:
and ax, 03h ; we use bit masking to get the last two bits of 
; the binary number, and if both of them are zero, we know that
; the number is divisible by 4
; the answer, after the logical operation, is stored in the first operand
cmp ax, 0h 
jne APPEND_ZERO

; after this point, all of the zeros are even are ready to be printed to the console
call newline
jmp PRINTING_DEM_BITS

DECREASE_NUM_BITS:
dec number_of_bits
PRINTING_DEM_BITS:
pop cx ; pops the most significant bit and loads it into register DX
; now dh has the bit we want to print,
add cx, 30h ; to convert the number into it's ASCII form for printing
mov dx, cx
mov ah, 02h
int 21h 
cmp number_of_bits, 0h
jne DECREASE_NUM_BITS

; End of main() proper

; Returning to ms-dos
mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h

main endp
end main
```

Whenever I input numbers below 512 i displays correctly but when I input a number greater than or equal to 512 it has an infinite loop.
I'm a newbie here please help. Thank you

Comment: Learn to use a debugger to step through your code. Other than that, the `cmp al, 01h` with the comment `if it's zero` is very suspicious.

Comment: There is also a bit of a trick if you use one of the lesser known BCD related instructions on the x86. `AAA` comes to mind. Somehow I doubt your professor would be happy with such a solution.

Comment: @Jester I just forgot to change the comments it used to be cmp al, 0h

Comment: @MichaelPetch I really don't get you, I'm a newbie here, I'm sorry

Comment: Note that `div two` will destroy `ah` which you might need if the input is above `512`. In any case, using `div` to divide by 2 is not recommended, a simple shift right is all you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`div two` performs 'AL = AX / two'. If the result won't fit into `AL` (>255), you get a 'divide overflow error'. This is the case, if AX > 511. Change the division to a WORD-division.

Replace

```
...
.data
...
two db 2
...
.code
...
do:
div two ; after division, the remainder (the digit we want) is stored in the AH register
mov cl, ah ; we copy ah to bh so that we can use AX again
push cx ; the stack now has the digits of the number in reverse order, so when we pop it
; the first value we pop is the value of the largest place value
inc number_of_bits
mov ah, 0h ; clear out AH because AX will be used again for division
cmp al, 01h ; we continue dividing the quotient, which is stored in AL and if it's zero, we move on
jne do
...
```

by

```
...
.data
...
two dw 2      ; WORD causes a WORD-division
...
.code
...
do:
xor dx, dx
div two         ; DX:AX / two -> AX, remainder DX
mov cx, dx
push cx ; the stack now has the digits of the number in reverse order, so when we pop it
; the first value we pop is the value of the largest place value
inc number_of_bits
cmp ax, 01h
jne do
...
```

There is an issue elsewhere: 512d is not 0010000000001b.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `div two` will destroy `ah` which you might need if the input is above `512`. What happens is you  have `AX=512`, and a byte-sized div that you seem to be using will produce an overflow since the result `256` doesn't fit in 8 bits. Presumably DOS ignores the generated exception, that's why you don't realize the problem.

In any case, using `div` to divide by 2 is not recommended, a simple shift right is all you need. If you shift left, you even get the digits in the correct order.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful!